# PowerBi-Javascript report embedding cluster details 403 error

Tags: typescript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm trying to display a power bi report in a typescript app.

I've successfully obtained an access token from AAD, and can in fact use it via the power bi rest api. I'd like to be able to use PowerBi-Javascript, for cleanliness and being able to apply filters. But I'm receiving a 403 error each time on a call to https://api.powerbi.com/powerbi/globalservice/v201606/clusterdetails, saying 'TokenExpired' - even when the token is freshly generated and should be valid for at least an hour.

The code to embed the report looks like this:

```
private embedReport(accessToken: string): powerBiClient.Embed {
  const element = this.getDisplayElement();
  const reportId = this.getReportId();
  const config = {
    type: 'report',
    id: reportId,
    tokenType: powerBiClient.models.TokenType.Aad,
    accessToken: accessToken
  };
  return this.powerBiService.embed(element, config);
```

`getDisplayElement` returns the appropriate HTMLElement, `getReportId` the id of the report to display, `powerBiClient` is the powerbi-javascript import, and `powerBiService` is an instance of `powerBiClient.service.Service`.

I've attempted this with reports I own, and with reports in a group (adding the groupId to the config).

How can I fix this error?

Comment: If you are trying to do more than just embed a report, it is not clear from the question. What is this clusterdetails API? I have never seen it before, but have been able to embed reports and individual visualisations without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, switching tokenType to - models.TokenType.**Embed** worked successfully.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing the `embedUrl` option in the config (see [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embedding-Basics) from the documentation). This is returned from the Power BI REST API, for example in the [get reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getreports#examples) API.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this using Angular 7 as follows.

**Component:**

```
showReport() {
 let accessToken = 'your access token’;
   // Embed URL
   let embedUrl = 'your embed URL';
   // Report ID
   let embedReportId = 'your embed report ID';
   let config = {
     type: 'report',
     pageName: 'aaa',
     name: 'Chamila',
     accessToken: accessToken,
     embedUrl: embedUrl,
     id: embedReportId,
     permissions: pbi.models.Permissions.All,
     viewMode: pbi.models.ViewMode.Edit,
     settings: {
       localeSettings: {
         language: "en",
         formatLocale: "es"
       },
     }
   };
   // Grab the reference to the div HTML element that will host the report.
   let reportContainer = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById('reportContainer');
   // Embed the report and display it within the div container.
   let powerbi = new pbi.service.Service(pbi.factories.hpmFactory, pbi.factories.wpmpFactory, pbi.factories.routerFactory);
   let report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config);
 }
```

**Html :**

```
<div id="reportContainer"></div>
```

Replace appropriate access token, embed url and report ID. It works perfectly for me.

Comment: what does this line do in this case? and where does pbi and factories things come from. I'm a newbie please help
  let powerbi = new pbi.service.Service(pbi.factories.hpmFactory, pbi.factories.wpmpFactory, pbi.factories.routerFactory);